# Event wont fire in custom control

Tags: c#, asp.net, custom-controls

I am trying to create a simple custom control where in there is a image button on the control along with a label.

the problem that i am facing is that the image button appears just fine along with the specified properties. But somehow when i click on the image button it does not generate the click event. the page simply refreshes.

Can some one please tell me what is the mistake ???

```
public override ControlCollection Controls
{
    get
    {
        EnsureChildControls();
        return base.Controls;
    }
}

protected override void RenderContents(HtmlTextWriter output)
{
    //CreateChildControls();
    AssociateValuesWithProperties();

    ibFirst.RenderControl(output);
    output.RenderEndTag();
}

protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    Controls.Clear();

    // Set subcontrols behavior
    //adding the event handlers to the image buttons
    ibFirst.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(ibFirst_Click);
}

private void AssociateValuesWithProperties()
{
    ibFirst.ImageUrl = FirstImageSrcNormal;
    ibFirst.AlternateText = FirstImageAltText;
    ibFirst.ToolTip = FirstImageAltText;
}

protected void ibNext_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    this.CurrentPage++;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah!!
I found the solution to my problem.

in the function CreateChildControls() we should also add the controls to the control collection. once i did that the code worked just fine.

thanks